# Can you explain the intuition of the product rule in a vector case?

Tags: calculus

My notes gives the product rule as follow:

Let $Z:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{n\times n} $ and $x:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$ be differentiable. Then $Zx:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n$ is differentiable and $\frac{d}{dt}Zx=\dot{Z}x+Z\dot{x}$.

I don't understand what this is trying to say. So $Z$ is a map which maps real numbers to an $n\times n$ matrix with entries in the complex field, and $x$ is a map which maps real numbers to an $n\times1$ matrix with entries in the complex field.

What is $Zx$ then? Multiplying two maps to give another map? And then we are trying to differentiate a map?

Please could you help me understand the intuition of the product rule in the vector case. Thanks.

Comment: maybe $Z:\mathbb{C^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$?

Comment: The expression $Z \circ x$ does not seem to make sense, because $x$ returns a vector in $\mathbb C^n$ as output, and $Z$ takes a real number as input.

Comment: I have written the statement word for word as it is in the provided notes for my class

Comment: Zx is multiplying a vector by a matrix. It can't be the composition, because that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If $Z$ is a complex $(n\times n)$-matrix and $x$ is a complex $n\times1$ column vector then $Zx$ is again a complex $n\times1$ column vector in the usual way: $Zx$ is the image of $x\in{\mathbb C}^n$ under the linear map $Z:\>{\mathbb C}^n\to{\mathbb C}^n$.

Now in your case the matrix $Z$ as well as the vector $x$ depend differentiably on "time" $t$. It follows that the image vector $y:=Zx$ depends on $t$ as well:$$y(t):=Z(t) x(t)\ .$$ We are interested in the "time" derivative $\dot y(t)$. When computing this derivative we have to be aware that the map $B(Z,x):=Zx$ is **bilinear** in its two variables $Z$ and $x$. This bilinearity automatically enforces the product rule
$${d\over dt}B\bigl(Z(t),x(t)\bigr)=B\bigl(\dot Z(t),x(t)\bigr)+B\bigl(Z(t),\dot x(t)\bigr)\ ,$$
which then leads to the formula you have doubts with.